# Multi-threaded application crash - possible memory corruption?

Tags: c#, memory, locking, memory-corruption

I have a multi-threaded application in c# which basically uses lock() to access a dictionary. There are 2 threads, a consumer and a producer. The locking mecanism is very simple. This application runs under heavy load for weeks without a problem.

Today it just crashed. I digged into WinDbg to see the Exception and it was a KeyNotFound when accessing the Dictionary.

What problems could cause this crash? Should I consider that memory corruption eventually may occur or not?

Comment: It is much more likely that you have a bug in your code that tries to get a key which does not exist. But without seeing your code it is just a wild guess why and where your code crashes.

Comment: Race conditions can be rare, so running for weeks does not indicate it's correct. Post the (locking) code if you want some insight.

Comment: Also, if you have the opportunity and you're running .NET 4.0, you might consider looking into `ConcurrentDictionary`.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx

Answer (score 9):

Making the locking too fined-grained could cause this.  For example:

```
    bool hasKey(string key) {
        lock (_locker) {
            return _dictionary.ContainsKey(key);
        }
    }
    int getValue(string key) {
        lock (_locker) {
            return _dictionary[key];
        }
    }
```

And then using it like this:

```
    void Kaboom() {
        if (hasKey("foo")) {
            int value = getValue("foo");
            // etc..
        }
    }
```

That won't work, the dictionary could change between the hasKey and the getValue call.  The entire operation needs to be locked.  And yes, this goes wrong once a month or so.

```
    bool tryGetValue(string key, out int value) {
        lock (_locker) {
            if (!hasKey(key)) return false;
            value = getValue(key);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good example and explanation.

Comment: Excellent answer, much insight.

Answer (score 0):

We have noticed various problems in our CMS framework code while using

dictionary.ContainsKey... instead we changed the code to use a try..catch block and amazingly, it has fixed our issues... please also try to change your function to something like this:

```
 int getValue(string key) {
            lock (_locker) {
    try {
     return _dictionary[key];
    } catch {
    return null // or "" or whatever would fit....
    }
            }
        }
```

see if it helps...